# How to upgrade PHP cURL to version >= 7.23 in Ubuntu

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I have curl version 7.22 on my Ubuntu 12.04.5 vm. I need to upgrade to at least 7.23 but I am unable to locate a tutorial online on how to "upgrade" php curl on the net. The PHP version is 5.3.14 and this must stay the same.

Any ideas how to do this upgrade in Ubuntu 12?

Comment: Follow this guide: http://pavelpolyakov.com/2014/11/17/updating-php-curl-on-ubuntu/